Oracle database backup recovery
Just startet to study Oracle, i need to restore database backup. Log file said it was made in Oracle Database 10g Enterprise. I have Oracle XE 18, is it even possible to make it for XE version usind RMAN or some other tools? Below list of files that i have in archive.
>   configFFH.ora
>   ffdacs-nfs-backup-2024-06-17.tar.gz 
>   initFFH.ora
>   ffhbackup
    >   arch_1_56543.arc
    >   arch_1_56544.arc
    >   arch_1_56545.arc
    >   arch_1_56546.arc
    >   arch_1_56547.arc
    >   arch_1_56548.arc
    >   arch_1_56549.arc
    >   arch_1_56550.arc
    >   arch_1_56551.arc
    >   arch_1_56552.arc
    >   arch_1_56553.arc
    >   control01.ctl
    >   dcomm.cache
    >   ffhactivity01.dbf
    >   ffhactivity_idx01.dbf
    >   ffhactivity_idx02.dbf
    >   ffhbackup2.log
    >   ffhconfig01.dbf
    >   ffhconfig02.dbf
    >   ffhconfig03.dbf
    >   ffhconfig04.dbf
    >   ffhdetail01.dbf
    >   ffhdetail_idx01.dbf
    >   ffhsummary01.dbf
    >   ffhsummary_idx01.dbf
    >   FFH_backup.log
    >   fsdump
    >   hot_db_files.lst
    >   sysaux01.dbf
    >   sysaux02.dbf
    >   system01.dbf
    >   temp01.dbf
    >   undo.dbf


There are two separate task here: restore and recover database and perform upgrade.
Let's start with the first one.
Let's pretend you have instance of 10G installed.
First of all you have to create an instance and start it with nomount mode. To do it you should put parameter file initFFH.ora in correct or default location, create password file so you can connect as sysdba and run SQLPLUS
sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL> startup nomount;

Next, put copy of your controlfile to location defined in  CONTROL_FILES parameter in initFFH.ora and mount your database
SQL> alter database mount;

Now it's time to restore database. If your *.dbf files are databafile copies just copy it to locations stored in your controlfile. If your dbf files are RMAN backups you need RMAN command to restore database, however based on names looks like they are datafile copies.
After you copy datafiles try to recover the database by applying archive logs. Put your *.arc files to location the Oracle can reach (defined in LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_n) and issue
SQL> recover database until cancel;

Oracle should apply archived logs until it failed to apply the next one arch_1_56554.arc. In this moment you have to cancel application and try to open your database.
SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS;

So here are steps you should complete

startup nomount
mount
restore datafiles
recover
open

Second problem is upgrade. Unfortunately
https://asktom.oracle.com/ords/asktom.search?tag=migration-to-18c-from-version-10g
you cannot directly upgrade from 10G to 18 so you have to do it twice. For example upgrade to version 11 or 12 and upgrade to 18
Edit. Regarding upgrade
There are a lots of good articles about upgrade like https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/upgrading-to-18c
In the nutshell
install intermittent version (11 or 12) in new $ORACLE_HOME
start old instance with old database as usual
Run preupgrade script from new version. This script won't update but review your installation and print it's findings
recompile invalid objects via utlrp.sql
Next step is starting new instance with old database using special command
SQL>startup upgrade

Keyword upgrade means ignore errors caused by version inconsistency.
Actual upgrade is done by running upgrade script like catupgrd.sql or the other scripts mentioned in Oracle upgrade guide for your version.
After the script completed it's work restart the instance in normal mode
Check alert.log for errors
recompile invalid objects via utlrp.sql
Repeat the process with target instance 18

Thank you for answer. I will install oracle 10g and try to do it. And initFFH.ora file don't have CONTROL_FILES parameter but configFFH.ora have 3 files in it, but i have only one of those files control01.ctl. Should I use this file? And about default location for initFFH.ora, after I create DB instance, I should put file in this DB folder like here: \oracle\product\10.2.0\Db_1\database\ ?

You should copy control01.ctl to all 3 location and rename it to control02.ctl and control03.ctl. Default location of init file on windows is $ORACLE_HOME/database/init$ORACLE_SID.ora but on UNIX it's $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/init$ORACLE_SID.ora

So, i created database instance named "FFH", shuted it down, copied initFFH.ora to (in my case) "D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\database", made startup nomount. So now I have to move my control files to some location. When i created FFH instance it created 3 control files, i tried to replce them and mount but got an error: ORA-00218:  ??? 'D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\FFH\CONTROL01.CTL' ??? DB_BLOCK_SIZE (0). Perhaps it because configFFH.ora have next path for control files: control_files = (/ffhdb/control01.ctl,  /ffhdb/control02.ctl, /ffhredolog/control03.ctl)?

And one more question, I don't know if this backup was made on linux or Windows, but if it was made on linux I need to restore it on linux as well?

I guess Oracle was not able to find or read the controlfile. I think you should restore on linux. The only way to transfer file to Windows is to use RMAN backup.

Also note that Oracle 10g will not be supported on current/modern versions of Linux. You may need to find a 20 year old operating system to go with the 20 year old database software.
